# SubString and CharIndex in sql join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @TABLE_A TABLE  (ID INT,NAME_A VARCHAR(100),VAL INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE_A VALUES(1,'1-06-734-01791/01',900),(2,'NAME2/2/F',100),(3,'NAME3/3',400),(4,'NAME44',80)

DECLARE @TABLE_B TABLE (ID INT,NAME_B VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE_B VALUES(1,'1-06-734-01791'),(2,'NAME2'),(3,'NAME3'),(4,'NAME4')

SELECT A.ID,b.NAME_b,A.VAL FROM @TABLE_A AS A
     INNER JOIN @TABLE_B AS B 
   ON B.NAME_B=SUBSTRING( A.NAME_A,1,CHARINDEX('/',A.NAME_A,1)-1)
```

This gives the following error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

In `join` section I don't want `like` operator because it will return more data.

Comment: it is not a good way to join tables. You should make sure NAME_A and NAME_B should not be manipulated when joining. having several values in the same column like that is bad practice

Comment: Now I edit the question this is sample data, how to solve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because your join condition is not robust against names without a slash; when you replace `NAME44` by `NAME4/4` in the sample data, you'll notice there's no error.

You can make your code more robust by first checking whether CHARINDEX returns zero (which means no slash was found):

```
INNER JOIN @TABLE_B AS B
  ON B.NAME_B = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', A.NAME_A, 1) = 0
                     THEN A.NAME_A
                     ELSE SUBSTRING(A.NAME_A, 1, CHARINDEX('/', A.NAME_A, 1) - 1)
                END
```

Answer (score 2):

From the sample data it seems that you are using Table B where you should use Table A instead. Just switch them around in the `JOIN` and you should be fine.

Try:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_A TABLE  (ID INT,NAME_A VARCHAR(100),VAL INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE_A VALUES(1,'NAME1/1/M/L',900),(2,'NAME2/2/F',100),(3,'NAME3/3',400),(4,'NAME4/4',80)

DECLARE @TABLE_B TABLE (ID INT,NAME_B VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE_B VALUES(1,'NAME1'),(2,'NAME2'),(3,'NAME3'),(4,'NAME4')

SELECT A.ID,A.NAME_A,A.VAL FROM @TABLE_A AS A
     INNER JOIN @TABLE_B AS B 
   ON B.NAME_B=SUBSTRING( A.NAME_A,1,CHARINDEX('/',A.NAME_A,1)-1)
```